# Integrating Kong and Azure Active Directory

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, kong

Have you tried integrate Kong with Azure Active Directory Authentication in kong?

What about it?

I've found this documentation ... but I am not sure if LDAP can to be applied with Azure Active Directory.

- [LDAP Authentication](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/ldap-auth/)
- [LDAP Authentication Advanced](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/ldap-auth-advanced/?_ga=2.16374718.945691851.1553508898-1940465463.1553167689)

  At this moment I am looking for it, but I think that LDAP does not apply to Azure Active Directory ... doesn't it?

I think,  that to use kong to control access via multi-factor authentication to resources or automate user provisioning between a Windows Server AD and our cloud apps or add SSO (allowing it to work with a user's pre-existing credentials) maybe could I to use [kong-openID auth plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/openid-connect/) or [Kong OAuth 2.0 Introspection plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/oauth2-introspection/) in order to use Azure Active Directory like a third party Authorization Server?

My intention is how to protect the Swagger API backend using kong and Azure, and in this way
I've read somethings [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad), but I  don't find any relation of  AAD itself with kong or some external API different to API Management instance service that they offer to their users

Could to be I wrong in my considerations here?

Is possible really work with kong authentication and authorization process and third party Auth servers like Azure Active Directory in my case?.

In this line,  Could to be [Kong OAuth 2.0 Introspection plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/oauth2-introspection/) a good alternative to follow?

Comment: you'd need to use oAuth 2.0 and treat Azure AD as a third party authorization server

Comment: [Oauth2 Introspection](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/oauth2-introspection/) to be more exactly ... really? If I use it, Can I think in work  with protocols like OpenID, SAML or some IDP open source integrations?

Comment: i dont know a lot about oauth2 internal, but I've configured istio to check Azure AD B2C oauth token recently like any other oauth2 provider, so i assume kong can do the same with Azure AD